# Error in function which is scanning and displaying the elements of an array

Tags: arrays, c, function

I have to write a sub-program that will scan and display the numbers of an array like this:[4, 5, 6]
But even though I am having no syntax problem, the function gives unexpected errors.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int display();

int display()
{
    int i, size;
    int array[size];
    printf("How many numbers will be in your array?\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Input the numbers of your array:\n");
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

printf("[");
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("%d", array[i]);
    for(i=0; i<size-1; i++)
    {
        printf(",");
    }
}
printf("]");
}
int main()
{
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error screen ?

Comment: As an input, it only takes 2 integers(even if I entered for ex 4 numbers), but displays only the first one

Comment: I added an answer to your problem please check it and tell me if you have any other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the **solution:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int display();

int display()
{
    int i, size;
    printf("How many numbers will be in your array?\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int array[size];
    printf("Input the numbers of your array:\n");
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

printf("[");
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("%d", array[i]);
    if(i != size-1){
        printf(",");
    }
}
printf("]");
}
int main()
{
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**
You initialize the array before scanning the `size` variable so the value of the array will depend on the garbage `size` value so you need to modify your code like this.

And for printing the `,` it is not better to use 2 loops and increase the same variable which is `i` so I used a condition `if` to do that in another better way.